# Actionscript 3 Search for string in array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have a problem with searching for strings in an array. I want to search for one word and if it exists, I want to trace the position of the string in the array.

I believe it should be something like this:

```
if (myArray contains "11111111") {
    trace("*position*")
} else {
    trace("cant find it");
}
```

Comment: Please post your entire code, including the array.

Comment: This is how my array looks
var deltakere:Array = new Array ();
var telefon:Array = new Array();

I fill in data using input text when the application is running

Comment: These are two arrays. Please understand that we cannot read your mind and do not see the code that you are not showing us. Add the information about the array(s) to your question, if they are both relevant to the question. (there's an edit button below the list of tags) Please clarify which array you want to search. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of syntax are you using there and have you even checked the documentation of the `Array` class? That should be the first thing you check always, as there is a pretty straightforward method for it:

```
var arr:Array = ["1111", "2222", "3333"];

trace(arr.indexOf("3333")); //traces the index: 2
```